# Trying to understand match_template from skimage.feature

Tags: scikit-image, matchtemplate

I'm trying to understand someone's code from match_template, but I couldn't understand the below process. Let's say there's a picture he's going to chop several parts. The picture is saved in:

```
ImagenTotal = np.asarray(Image.open('./redmangos.jpg'))
```

Then he selects 2 places on that picture and the coordinates are:

```
puntosinteres = [[189.7038558467742, 111.99546370967738],[211.1748235887097, 187.9696572580645]]
```

Since match_template needs two arguments - one is the original picture and another is what he's going to use to compare. Then the following process looks like this:

```
xinteres = int(puntosinteres[0][0]) 
yinteres = int(puntosinteres[0][1])
radio = 10
imagenband = ImagenTotal[:,:,0]
templateband = ImagenTotal[yinteres - radio : yinteres + radio, xinteres - radio : xinteres + radio, 0]
result= match_template(imagenband, templateband)
result = np.where(result>0.8)
```

I don't know what he's trying to do on imagenband and templateband. Could someone point me to a direction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imagenband` grabs the 0th channel from `ImagenTotal`, to get a single grayscale image. `templateband` grabs a small, 20x20 rectangle from `yinteres - radio` (radius in Spanish) to `yinteres + radio` on the rows axis and `xinteres - radio` to `xinteres + radio` on the columns axis.

To read more on how indexing works for numpy arrays, you can read the official documentation on indexing here:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#basics-indexing

There are links there for more advanced indexing topics.